# nodejs express res.render in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, render

i have a problem with res.render() in expressjs
i use ajax to request on this route:

```
route.get('/about',authentication,(req,res)=>{
    res.render('about');
});
```

I did some search and found out that `res.render` does not work with ajax calls
so how can I change and render page without `res.render()`.

If I remove the `res.render` and `console.log` it it will work actually any code work but not `res.render` (by clicking a link I send a token in header with ajax request then in my route I have an authentication middleware that get the token then redirects the user to `about.ejs` page)

I just want to change the page. Any idea will help guys.
thx
here is the front-end request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#about').click(function(){
         // window.location.href='/about';
           $.ajax({
              method:'get',
              url:'http://localhost:5000/about',
              headers:{"authtoken":localStorage.getItem('authToken')}
           }).done(()=>{
               // window.location.href='/about';
           }).catch(e=>console.log('header.ejs error'));
       });
    });
```

Comment: res.render() means you are returning a view from the server. Why you want to return a view in ajax. I mean what is your expected result?

Comment: i just want to render a page if you have any other solution say plz.i just started programming so i dont know the right ways.plz let me know

Comment: You should show the client side JavaScript code that you use to request the `about` page. `res.render` can work with ajax request, but it depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: @t.niese i updated the question and you can see the code now.thx

Comment: You do nothing with the response int the `.done(()=>{ }` callback, so why do you expect that something should be displayed to the client? jQuery does not magically replace content on the site if you do a `$.ajax`.

Comment: i did it in server with res.render and nothing happend.i also tried window.location.href='/about' and the problem with this is that it will fire another request to same url so one request in ajax and one with this code so i removed it.do you know another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`res.render` composes a html page using templates and sends the final composed result from the server to the client. It does not issue a rendering of the page in the client window.

If the request is issued by entering the URL in the addressbar of the browser, then the browser will do the request and render the result the server sends.

If you do an ajax request you will receive that response, but you are responsible to do something with it in the `.done` callback. The browser does not magically know what has to be done with the data if you do an ajax request. And because you do not have anything in your `.done` callback nothing will happen.

So you have to do something like that:

```
.done(response => {
    var bodyContent = response.match(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/)[1]
  $('body').html(bodyContent);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Make a public URL, say http://your-web-site.com/redirect_destination.html

Step-2: On making ajax request from front-end, redirect user to that page using [`.redirect()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) method on `response`

**EDIT:**

The point is, I don't think it's possible to render page by making an ajax request. You can prepare a URL which renders your desired page and redirect user to that URL using [`.redirect()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) method.

Comment: i have an authentication middleware so if any one wants to visit About page should be authenticated.if i redirect them to a public page so what is the benefit of authentication because anyone can put the public url in browser and see the page.am i right?

Comment: The point of my answer is to make you aware of the `.redirect()` method my friend. You didn't mention any of those authentication details in your question. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `ajax` is used to  update a portion of page using some resposne from server without refreshing page. If you want  to navigate to another route instead of ajax use form submits or `href`. If you stick to ajax then return a JSON from the server and do the alteration using javascript

```
requestHandler=(req,res)=>{
 res.json({data:{}})
}
```

Comment: i didnt get it.how can i render the page with res.json?i have about.ejs and i want to render it

Comment: If you are using ajax res.render() wil not work.Instead you can return json data via res.json() method and you can raed that json on ajax success function at browser and do necessary changes as I mentioned. or else you have to do form submission and do res.render(). hope you understand

Comment: @M14 ajax does not require to return json, you can in fact request any regular html page using ajax, and replace the page content base on the html response.

Comment: i got what you said but i have no form.i click on a link then the ajax request will be sent.

Comment: @t.niese ya true

Comment: @Vfx Master then it is a normal request. use try{}catch() to see any error happends

Comment: @t.niese so how can i render html with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Your router will not render page ,it will send only response and I didnt get just for page rendering, why you are calling ajax request on click event.If dont mind you can write logic on click and change window.location with your router. It will render particular page, for that your router should be something like this:

```
    // about page route (http://localhost:8080/about)
    router.get('/about',isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/about.html'));
    }); 

   function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  // do any checks you want to in here

  // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
  // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
  if (req.user.authenticated)
      return next();

  // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
  res.redirect('/');
 }
```

And change your url on click to http://localhost:8080/about

Comment: as you can see in my code i have an authentication middleware so i use ajax to set token in header and send it to server thats why i use ajax