# Node.js and Express res.render() not doing anything?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I have looked at all the related posts and and spent a long time googling this, but have yet to find a solution. I am trying to render an ejs template, however, nothing seems to be happening. My code:

Front end script:

```
 $('#search').click(function(){
         var query =$('#search-query').val();//get value from searchbar
         var url = '/search/' + query;
         $.ajax({
         url: url,
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('error');


  })
}
```

Backend:

```
app.get("/search/:query", function(req, res){
  var query = req.params.query;
  Note.find({course: query}, function(err, foundNotes){//search database
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(foundNotes);//this displays the expected results from searching the database
      res.render('search.ejs', {notes: foundNotes});//appears to do nothing
      console.log('upload');//this also gets logged
    }

  })
});
```

Basically when a button is clicked I want it to make a GET request to the '/search/:query' path with the value in the input as the search query. I am then searching a database and then rendering an ejs template that displays the search results.

The troubling line is the res.render('search.ejs, {notes: foundNotes}). It doesn't seems to do anything. If I enter the path manually it works, but it does not seem to work from the button click. I think I may be missing a key concept here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to re-render your template or render a new page, you need to send the user to a new route using an anchor tag with the appropriate query parameters appended to that anchor tag. If you want this to act like a single page app, you need to use `res.send` and then re-render the template on the front end using the data your server responded with.

Comment: As i understand he just want to render on the fly some element of the page. He can do this in ajax like this.

Comment: @Daphoque you can't respond to an ajax request with `res.render`

Comment: Ajax is just a way to process http request, you can return what you want inside it. Res.render just proceed a template then send text. Of course it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render engine is set correctly before your app.get?

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

What do you see in response in the network inspector ?

Example :

// my ajax handler

```
router.get("/a", function(req, res){ res.render("a.ejs",{a: 11})});
```

// my ejs file

```
<p>
<span>hello <%- a %></span>
</p>
```

// my ajax request in front side :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/a",
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
      // in data i have : <p><span>hello 11</span></p>

      document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('error');


  }})
```

Comment: It's because he is responding to the ajax request with `res.render`. He has to respond with `res.send` and then handle the data on the frontend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740067/nodejs-express-res-render-in-ajax-calls

Comment: Oh ok , so the res.render() will return the html which I must then handle on the client-side?

Comment: res.render will proceed your template and send the response as html

Comment: You can then do what you want with it, as in the example

Comment: Thank you, I was able to resolve my problem with your suggestion.