# Cannot connect frontend and backend in Express, Node and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, express-handlebars

Thank you for taking time to read my question. Currently I am working on using a  dropdown list using "select" tag for the user to select from. and totally stuck on the following. localhost, all other pages and functions working properly . yet Cannot connect frontend and backend in Express, Node and Javascript

Any help would be appreciated .

Handlebar template I use is as follows.

```
<div class="container center">
  <div class="row">
  <h3 class="flow-text">Search for items you can exchange your item with</h3>
  <div class="col s12">
    <label>Search by Category</label>
  <select id="category" class="browser-default" onchange="getItems()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>I am looking for...</option>
    <option value="2">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="3">Clothes</option>
    <option value="4">Fruits</option>
    <option value="1">Other</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

{{#each editedItems as |i|}}
<div class="col s12 m4">
      <!---->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="/images/strawberry.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">{{i.title}}</span>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red" href="/item/{{i.id}}"><i class="material-icons">zoom_in</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="truncate">{{i.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---->
    </div>
{{/each}}

</div>

</div>

<script src="/js/searchItems.js"></script>
```

On the **change of the selection** javascript will run a function called get items in the `/js/searchItems.js`. I checked wheather the script is linked by using a simple alerts. One each change those alerts worked before I put the actual function code.

`searchItems.js` has the following code.

```
function getItems() {
    const select = document.getElementById('category');
    let option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    let categoryId = option.value;

    searchByCategory(categoryId);
   
}

const searchByCategory = async (categoryId) => {
    const response = await fetch(`/items/${categoryId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Response ok");
    } else {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  };
```

And in the backend following route is written to get the items by using this category id taken from the option value in the dropdown list.

```
router.get('/items/:category', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const categoryId = req.params.category;
      const existingItems = await Item.findAll({
      where:{
          category_id : categoryId
      },
      order: [['id','DESC']],
    });
    
      const editedItems = existingItems.map((item) => item.get({ plain: true }));
    
      res.render('search', { 
          editedItems, 
          logged_in: req.session.logged_in 
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

All other routes in the same route file are working as expected. I tried to simulate this route using Insomina Core and it rendered the page as I expected.

But in the localhost, all other pages and functions working properly. But, when I change the options in the dropdown list (as per the screenshot below), items related to categories would not appear.

[image]

But it gives "respose ok" --- looking at the console as follows.

[image]

I am using **handlebars as a templating engine, Express server, MySQL and Nodejs.**

Any support would be much appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? If so, what errors?

Comment: You don't mention in your question, but I assume you are getting `"Response ok"`, right?

Comment: Heya, thanks for the reply. I am getting response ok. That's correct. Actually what I tried to do was to reload the search results by sending a request to the backend '/items/2' or whatever category number, selected on the dropdown list.

Comment: Ok, I'll try explain what's wrong in an answer, gimme me a min.

Comment: Duplicate of this question, btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740067/nodejs-express-res-render-in-ajax-calls

Comment: @RichardDunn Hey, thanks a lot for that. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure that out with the above question. If I may ask you this, hope you will be able help me out. I tried console logging the response object coming from the backend. It has so many things. I tried serialising that in the backend, but still when the object is passed to front end, it is a mess. Is there is any possibility, I can create the part of search results injected using frontend javascript?

Comment: See my answer below, hopefully it explains a little better. In short, use `res.json(data)` on the backend and handle the result on the frontend with JavaScript.

Comment: @RichardDunn I will give my best shot and will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your time. I read your answer below. It makes a lot more sense to me now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two types of HTTP request. An XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) and a regular HTTP request.

You are calling using ajax, but you are responding from the server as if it were a normal page view. Normally, in Express, you'd respond to an ajax request using [response.send([body])](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) or by using one of the convenience methods such as [response.json([body])](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json). These typically format the response body some way and/or add some headers, but they are fundamentally all the same. I strongly suggest you browse the linked page to help your understanding.

Your browser handles "normal" http requests by rendering them as a page. But your ajax lib, (in this case `fetch`) is getting the response and doing nothing with it. Typically, you'd write some JavaScript to handle the response, i.e. parse the body and manipulate the page in some way.

However, since you are returning HTML and not JSON, you could possibly inject this HTML into a part of the page. See [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). But this is arguably an archaic way to do it, I'd suggest having your initial template be manipulated purely though JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are not doing anything with your response from the `searchByCategory` function, also its an async function and you do not await it, so maybe theres something there.

Not knowing if any of the code works i would go step by step starting in the ui;

1. Is `getItems()` ever called
2. Does it get `categoryId` like you expect
3. Is `searchByCategory()` being reached and does it respond correctly
4. I am not super familiar with the express-handlebars framework, but if you could i would suggest simplifying the backend.

Comment: 1. On change it actually called the getItems function, because it worked with alert function before this code.